# Declare object in header

Tags: c++, class, object, header

How can I declare an object without initializing it?

This is my header file

```
    #include "shader.h"

    Class Renderer {
        private:
        kaarez::graphics::Shader m_terrainShader;
    };
```

And my source file

```
    #include "Renderer.h"
    #include "Shader.h"

    Renderer::Renderer() {
        //Load terrain shader
        m_terrainShader =  kaarez::graphics::Shader("vertex.txt", "fragment.txt");
    }
```

I get the error that theres no appropriate default constructor available for Shader.

Shader is header-only, and it works when I declare it in the main method by `kaarez::graphics::Shader terrainShader("vertex.txt", "fragment.txt");`

What is wrong?

Comment: Your question is kinda unsolvable because C++ is **case-sensitive**. There is no `Class` keyword and `shader.h` is not `Shader.h`.

Comment: Apparently my IDE/compiler is not case-sensitive for includes. Didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Initialise the member variable in the constructors member initializer list like so:

```
Renderer::Renderer() : m_terrainShader("vertex.txt", "fragment.txt") {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to initialize `m_terrainShader` in the class [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) since it is not default constructable.

```
Renderer::Renderer() : m_terrainShader("vertex.txt", "fragment.txt"){}
```

The reason you have to do this is that when you enter the body of the constructor all of the class members are already initialized.  Since `m_terrainShader` cannot be default initialized you have to explicitly initialize it.

Comment: Thank you, but is there no way that I can initialize Shader in the Renderer constructor? This solution is fine atm, but in the future I would like to initialize it in the constructor for several reasons.

Comment: Not if `Shader` is not default constructable.  It is the preferred and sometimes only way to construct an object.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Comment: Is the only solution the to re-initialize it?

Comment: @KaareZ Why would you need to re-initialize it?  You can construct the members directly in the initialization list.  can you show me an example of what you are trying to do and why list initialization does not work for you?

Comment: I want to be able to choose which "vertex.txt" and "fragment.txt" to use. For example by loading a settings file in the Renderer constructor. Also I'm not a fan of the style, but that is of course second priority.

Comment: @KaareZ The only way is to use a pointer (`std::unique_ptr` ideally) for the `m_terrainShader` then.

Comment: @KaareZ It could also be possible to use a function to create the object that you want and call that function in the initializer list.   `m_terrainShader(create_shader(some_values))`

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe not precisely an answer (and many years late), but in C++11 or greater, you can use a unique pointer (or a shared pointer).

in the header do:

```
unique_ptr<kaarez::graphics::Shader> m_terrainShader;
```

And in the code do

```
m_terrainShader.reset(new kaarez::graphics::Shader("vertex.txt", "fragment.txt"));
```

It's safer than a pointer because you don't have to worry about failure to delete it or deleting it without assigning it.